# Using data from other database to populate a new database

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database `DB1` and want to move data from `DB1` to `DB2`. But only want some of the data to be moved.

I want all the rows from `DB1` that have a `catParent` that is the same as I Id from `DB2`. And I only want the `DB1.catDescription = DB2.Name and DB1.catLink = DB2.URL`

How do I manage that? Do I need a sub select query inside my insert query and how is the syntax for this?

DB1

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[category](
    [catID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [catDescription] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [catParent] [bigint] NULL,
    [catSortOrder] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [catLink] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [catShow] [tinyint] NULL,
    [catTarget] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [catAssign] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [primary key] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [catID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

DB2

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Guid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [ntext] NULL,
    [AssignArticles] [bit] NULL,
    [URL] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Target] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Publish] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ParentCategoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Sort] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RequireLogin] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LevelVal] [int] NULL,
    [PageLayoutId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [M03PictureId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Sitemap] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Search] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LinkText] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Categories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: You have more columns in target than source, and they're also NOT NULL columns. Where are you getting the other values from? (This will affect the query you need to use).

Comment: @StuartMoore the default for the other columns will be '1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
update DB2.[dbo].[Categories]
set
    DB2.[dbo].[Categories].Name = DB1.[dbo].[category].catDescription,
    DB2.[dbo].[Categories].URL = DB1.[dbo].[category].catLink
from
    DB2.[dbo].[Categories] inner join
    DB1.[dbo].[category] on DB2.[dbo].[Categories].ID = DB1.[dbo].[category].catParent
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to tables on the same instance using full name which is: *database.schema.table*. For this you can do something like:

```
USE DB2
GO

INSERT INTO Categories(<insert columns>)
SELECT <select columns from cat table>
FROM DB1.dbo.category AS cat
INNER JOIN Categories
ON cat.catDescription = Categories.Name and cat.catLink = Categories.URL
AND cat.catParent = <your condition>
```

I'll let you sort out the insert and select columns, since mapping between database columns is not not trivial and you didn't provider enough information. I also don't understand what you mean by "I want all the rows from DB1 that have a catParent that is **the same as I Id from DB2**.", so you can fill in that condition too.

If you need to move ID too (which is IDENTITY column), remember to execute before INSERT statement SET IDENTITY_INSERT Categories ON and after you finish SET IDENTITY_INSERT Categories OFF.